# Perl Parse XML file over HTTP with a few extra lines

Tags: xml, perl, http

I'm trying to write a script that can gather information from an XML file from a remote server. The remote server requires authentication. I was able to authenticate since it uses basic authentication, but it appears that I'm unable to parse the data because of all the lines before the XML file. Is there a way to avoid getting all those lines and correctly parse the XML file?

**Code**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

use XML::Simple;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://192.168.1.10/getxml?/home/');
$ua->ssl_opts(SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE); #Used to ignore certificate
$req->authorization_basic('admin', 'test');
$test = $ua->request($req)->as_string;

print $test;
# create object
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

# read XML file
my $data = $xml->XMLin("$test");

# access XML data
print $data->{status}[0]{productID};
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 24 Sep 2014 01:12:20 GMT
Server: 
Content-Length: 252
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Client-Date: Wed, 24 Sep 2014 01:11:59 GMT
Client-Peer: 192.168.1.10:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: XXXXXXXXXXXX
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Client-SSL-Cipher: XXXXXXXXXXXX
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Status>
  <SystemUnit item="1">
    <ProductId item="1">TEST SYSTEM</ProductId>
  </SystemUnit>
</Status>
:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$test = $ua->request($req)->as_string;` invocation is returning a string representation of the entire request (headers plus content).

Change this to `$test = $ua->request($req)->content;`.

This will return only the content, minus the header.

Comment: And, you guessed it, `$test = $ua->request($req)->header` will return just the header. See [HTTP::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GAAS/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Request.pm)

Answer (score 0):

I would find a match for the first < and get the rest of the data from there. That will skip the first items which are not of interest to you.  The code would look like:

```
$test =~ m/(<.*)/s;
my $xmlData = $1;
my $data = $xml->XMLin("$xmlData");
# Fix the print to get the item for which I believe you are trying to obtain
print $data->{SystemUnit}{ProductId}{content}."\n";
```

where we capture < and everything which follows using the s modifier to indicate the items should be treated as one string of character (basically to ignore newlines).  The $1 is the captured data from the match statement, which I assigned to a variable in case you would like to print it or view it in the debugger.  In addition, I added the following to get "TEST SYSTEM" as the content of the ProductId Tag.

Comment: Thanks!! The answer from Snoopy removed the header, your answer for fixing my print statement was perfect!